# unable to record audio even when I interact with page

Tags: javascript, web-mediarecorder

I am using getUserMedia and mediaRecorder API to record audio.

even when I interact with the page and click to allow recording I get this error:

> DOMException: Could not start audio source

I'm using this code:

```
document.head.innerHTML += '<audio id="recordedAudio" crossorigin="anonymous"></audio>';
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio:true})
.then(stream => {
  rec = new MediaRecorder(stream);
  rec.ondataavailable = e => {
    audioChunks.push(e.data);
    if (rec.state == "inactive"){
    let blob = new Blob(audioChunks,{type:'audio/x-mpeg-3'});
    recordedAudio.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    }
  }
})
.catch(e=>console.log(e));
```

I remember earlier this day I run the code without any errors! What happened to chrome in hours!?

How can I fix this and what are the possible issues?

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear cache and restart the browser, in windows its like this:

```
Ctrl + Shift + R
```

Comment: I cleared the whole cache and cookies for one week... in firefox, I can see allow pop up here on chrome I can't!

Comment: To enable popups in Chrome: Settings -> Privacy and security -> Site settings -> Pop-ups and redirects -> Allowed

Answer (score 0):

This might not be related to user permission. Usually permissions errors will throw a `DOMException: Permission denied` exception.

Is it possible that the audio source is being used by another tab?

Also try checking the current setting for your page by clicking the tiny lock icon in the address bar

[image: microphone permission chrome]

Comment: I'm more confused now! I put the code in the question inside a function but I have access to `rec` and `audiochunck` from global scope!!! How did I do that?!

Comment: well these are separate issues. Did you declare audioChunks within the function? have a look here for more information about Scope https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope

Comment: I know scoping in javascript. I Haven't defined any variable . I Just used the above code inside of a function and then somewhere else I used `rec.start()` ?!